# How to setup apache redirect or custom 401 document on Kerberos SSO login failure

Tags: apache-2.2, kerberos, jboss

I have a working Kerberos SSO setup, I use apache and jboss with mod_jk. Apache is protecting (by kerberos) the auto-login.htm page with the following configuration:

```
<Location /auto-login.htm>  
AuthType           Kerberos  
AuthName           "Kerberos Active Directory Login"  
KrbMethodNegotiate on  
KrbMethodK5Passwd  on  
KrbAuthRealms      KRB.SOMEDOMAIN.COM  
KrbServiceName     HTTP/server.somedomain.com@KRB.SOMEDOMAIN.COM  
Krb5Keytab         /etc/krb/krb5.keytab  
KrbVerifyKDC       on  
KrbAuthoritative   on  
require            valid-user  
#ErrorDocument 401  /login.htm  
</Location>
```

This works 100% and I am able to login with Kerberos/SSO and read the remote_user variable in my java application.

Now the problem is that I want to redirect to a unprotected login.htm if the user was unable to log in via Kerberos/SSO. The solution I had in mind was to set a 401 ErrorDocument, however when I set this up by uncommenting the #ErrorDocument 401 in the code above it always redirects to login.htm as returning a 401 to request user credentials is inherently part of the Kerberos/SSO authentication process. Thus the result is users always end up at login.htm and never completes the Kerberos/SSO login process.

Any help or alternative solution will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance
Pierre

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order not to interrupt the Kerberos/SSO authentication process, use the following:

```
ErrorDocument 401 "<html><meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;url=/login.htm\"></html>"
```

This will cause a redirect to occur only when the user clicks cancel on the browser dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want `ErrorDocument 403`.  401 is returned when the server asks for authentication, 403 is returned when the client fails to provide authentication.  This is at least true when setting up x.509 authentication.

Comment: This is also the behavior that I expected, however with Kerberos SSO the final page a user is shown is a 401.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this:

```
ErrorDocument 401 /redirect-to-login
RewriteRule ^/redirect-to-login$ /login.html [R]
```